# print(np.reshape(x[0],(1,64,64,3))) I am getting reshape error x[0] it my first image number

Tags: python

```
----> 1 print(np.reshape(x[0],(64,64,3)))
      2 print(y[0])

<__array_function__ internals> in reshape(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in reshape(a, newshape, order)
    299            [5, 6]])
    300     """
--> 301     return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
    302 
    303 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     56     bound = getattr(obj, method, None)
     57     if bound is None:
---> 58         return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     59 
     60     try:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     45     except AttributeError:
     46         wrap = None
---> 47     result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
     48     if wrap:
     49         if not isinstance(result, mu.ndarray):

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (64,64,3)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the title is not sufficiently long to hold a readable and detailed explanation of the problem. Would you edit your post and put a description in the body of the question? If you can make it detailed, readers would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, we do not know the value of `x[0]`, or how it was computed / derived. Judging from the error message, `x[0]` seems to have a shape of 1, in which case an MRE would look like this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros(shape=(10, 1))
np.reshape(x[0],(64,64,3))  # produces the error message
```

As the error message suggests, the size of `x[0]` does not match the size of the target shape The size of an arrayis the product of the entries of the shape.

Specifically, an array of shape `(64, 64, 3)` requires a size of `64*64*3=12288` values.

However, `x[0]` only has one value, which is why `numpy` does not know how to carry out the conversion. You need to ensure that `x[0]` has the correct size. For example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros(shape=(1, 64*64*3))
np.reshape(x[0],(64,64,3)) # this should succeed
```